# Cannot Update Row In Oracle DB Using C# Library

Tags: c#, database, oracle

When I want to update row with type 'date' in oracle database through asp.net C# method it gives the following error:

error:
**ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP**

code:

```
string query = String.Format("update mms_meetings m set m.end_date = :end_date where m.id = :id");

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("", GetDBConnection());
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = query;

    OracleParameter opId = new OracleParameter();
    opId.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    opId.Value = meetId;
    opId.ParameterName = "id";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(opId);

    OracleParameter opDateEnd = new OracleParameter();
    opDateEnd.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
    opDateEnd.Value = dateEnd;
    opDateEnd.ParameterName = "end_date";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(opDateEnd);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();

    CloseDBConnection();
```

Comment: Which of type is the `end_date` in your DB?

Comment: Try changing order in which you are adding parameters to the order used in query - `end_date` first, `id` - second.

Comment: @Mikhail Oracle doesn't use parameter names to distinguish the appropriate one?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Sometimes it is, sometimes is's not, (for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959242/c-sharp-oracle-stored-procedure-parameter-order), so worth trying to place them in correct order :)

Comment: Placing in correct order was the problem.

Comment: I was also facing same issue, solved it by placing parameter in order exactly match with query :param. (BTW this thing is very annoying)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You must send the exact format for your date as specified in your table column. Check default format for your date column. Like

```
'yyyy/MM/dd'
```

2) If you are using OleDb or ODBC Connection, they both use **positional parameters** so order of adding the parameters is very important. Try changing the order of your parameter to see if it helps.

Comment: Positional parameters is the right answer. Thank you