# insert into select from ignoring last two rows issue

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert, dml

I have this atomic dml in oracle (code snippet-1)
I have 2936 row to insert but 2934 rows inserted.

Else where I have also this loop(code snippet-2), that only first 2934 taken into account but two last rows ignored

this happens in production env. which I have restricted access(the data is about 1 MB)

So in test env. I tried to reproduce same issue with same table structure and similar data, about 18.000 rows inserted successfully.

What could be issue that last two rows ignored?

*code snippet-1*

```
 INSERT INTO MY_TARGET_TABLE
  (
    COL1,
    COL2,
    COL3,
    ...
    COLN,
  )
  SELECT 
    B.YEAR,
    B.MONTH,
    P.SOME_COL,
    ...
    B.MY_DECIMAL_VALUE  
      FROM MY_SOURCE_TABLE B
      JOIN MY_SOURCE_VIEW P
      ...
   WHERE B.YEAR = P_YEAR
       AND B.MONTH = P_MONTH
       AND B.SOME_STATUS_ID = 5
       AND B.IS_ACTIVE = 0
       AND B.MY_DECIMAL_VALUE > 0;
```

*code snippet-2*

```
FOR ROW_ITEM IN(
        SELECT 
               COL1,
               COL2,
               COL3,
               ...  
               SUM(NVL(MY_DECIMAL_VALUE,0) / 100)

        FROM MY_SOURCE_TABLE B
        JOIN MY_SOURCE_VIEW P
            ON ...
       WHERE B.YEAR = P_YEAR
           AND B.MONTH = P_MONTH
           AND B.SOME_STATUS_ID = 5
           AND B.IS_ACTIVE = 0
           AND B.MY_DECIMAL_VALUE > 0;
         GROUP BY 
           ....
      )
      LOOP

      P_SOME_PROCEDURE(...)
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Alas this question is not answerable. Too many unknowns. If you can't reproduce it with your knowledge of the application and its business logic, what chance do we have? Instead of asking us you should be asking the gatekeepers to give you temporary privileged access to Production, or asking your boss to re-assign the ticket to somebody who can investigate the issue properly.

Comment: @APC a few days ago, I encountered a common pitfall of oracle with c#, BindByName properpty must be set: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143030/492258. I suspect similar issue thus I asked this question, any details can be provided upon request. By the way, I have access readonly to production. I can do select part with pl sql developer.

Comment: Violating any unique key constraint? Does similar rows exist in the table? Rows just doesn't go missing like this in Oracle.

Comment: @AdnanBhatti Both codes complete with out error. In case you mentioned, some error message should be produced IMO.

Comment: Yah errors are helpful only if we are NOT using exception when others not null. Anyway, if data was inserted then only other option is was it deleted? Any triggers? Can't really say what could have happened without looking at actual code and actual table definition.

Comment: @AdnanBhatti Already you provided a lot of suggestion thanks for info. I will look at them

Comment: @APC no not at all, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264134/insert-into-select-from-ignoring-last-two-rows-issue?noredirect=1#comment106597701_60264134) is just an example of pitfalls